# Is there a biological determinant for right- or left-handedness?

Tags: physiology, neurophysiology

When I was very young, I was sent by parents to examination where I was told both my hands are dominant in the same way. My parents preferred to make my life easier and chose to focus on my right hand development.

However, all my life I find myself naturally using my left hand - with a knife, to lift things, etc. Yesterday something happened that really twisted my perspective - I was playing bowling and I really sucked at it. And then, the moment I started playing with my left hand, I got perfect strikes.

I use my delicate motor abilities a lot with my right hand (drawing for instance), and now I wonder - how can I tell if I used the correct hand all my life?

Comment: This question ends with a question about the poster's personal life history. There is a biological question in the title, but it is never mentioned in the question itself. After five years, surely it is time to dump this question as completely off-topic.